# How to launch an "event" when my Boost::asio tcp server just start running ( AKA io_service.run() )?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-asio

Based on an boost::asio client/server relationship, I have to launch the client program from the server program only when the server thread is in a "**waiting to be connected**" state.

My question is how to have the knowledge of that state ?

As a sample use the [asio example/serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/)
[link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/), and replace the main function of server.cpp with that code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <concrt.h> // wait function
#include <future>
#include <thread>

void server_thread( std::promise<bool>& run )
{ 
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    s11n_example::server server(io_service, 123);
    // too early to run.set_value( true );
    io_service.run();
    // too late to run.set_value( true );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::promise<bool> run;
    std::thread thrd( server_thread, boost::ref( run ) );
    thrd.detach(); 

    bool launched = run.get_future().get();
    // server is waiting for connection
    // launch the client
    if( launched )
    {
        int rc = system( "start client.exe localhost 123" );
        if( rc )
            std::cerr << "system failed returning " << rc << std::endl ;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "server_thread failure" << std::endl ;

    std::cout << "hit a key to exit"  ;
    while( !_kbhit() )
        Concurrency::wait( 100 );

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: your server will accept a connection as a result of the `async_accept` callback, you can set the `future` result inside the callback.

Comment: @SamMiller I would like to synchronize on "ready to connect" state of the talk object. 
I presume that I have to install a handler in the talk object, and from that handler launch run.set_value( true ) ... But which handler and how ? That is the question !

async_accept is called when a connection is made, I want to synchronize on "able to accept a connection" state.

Comment: Boost.Asio's acceptors do not provide reactor based operations for accepting (i.e. connection ready to be accepted).

Comment: @tanner Thanks Tanner, but my server is necessarily stuck somewhere waiting (or looping) for a client, I try to find that in the bowels of asio, no success :-(

Comment: If you can provide the Boost version and an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for the `tcp_server_talk` class, we should be able to identify the problem.  As it stands, there is not much we can do to help beyond guessing.

Comment: @tanner I did it, anyway hopefully ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `s11n_example::server` is in a state where incoming connections will be queued immediately after the constructor call has completed.

---

It may be easier to understand this by defining a distinction between state and operations.  A state determines what the OS can do with the object; an application initiates operations that perform actions and may depend on state.  For example, when a socket in an *open* state, the OS will queue data; a *read* operation retrieves the queued data.  The same applies to the acceptors.  When an acceptor is in a *listen* state, the OS will queue connections; an *accept* operation will complete the connection, removing it from the queue.

An `acceptor`'s *[states]* and *transitions()* are as follows:

```
     .----> [closed] ------.     [closed]:    socket not open
     |                     |     [opened]:    socket open but not listening for
     |                     V                  connections
  close() <------.      open()   [listening]: incoming connections will be
     ^           |         |                  queued until accepted(), causing
     |           |         V                  the connection to be established
[listening]      '---- [opened]
     ^                     |
     |                     |
     '------ listen() <----'
```

The various overloaded constructors will result in the `acceptor` starting its lifetime in a closed, opened, or listening state.  In the case of [`s11n_example::server`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/server.cpp), the acceptor is constructed with an endpoint, so [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor/overload3.html) overload will result in the acceptor being in a listening state post-construction.  It is the equivalent of doing:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
tcp::endpoint endpoint_(tcp::v4(), 123);
tcp::acceptor acceptor_(io_service); // closed state
acceptor.open(endpoint_.protocol()); // opened state
acceptor.bind(endpoint);
acceptor.listen();                   // listening state
```

Therefore, the promise can be set after `server` is constructed and before `io_service.run()`:

```
void server_thread(std::promise<bool>& run)
{ 
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    s11n_example::server server(io_service, 123);
    // The server's acceptor is in a listening state, so connection attempts
    // will be queued even without the io_service event loop running.  The
    // server also has an outstanding asynchronous accept operation.
    run.set_value(true);
    // Run the service, this will start an asynchronous loop that accepts 
    // connections.
    io_service.run();
}
```

One subtlety to note is that Boost.Asio's acceptors do not provide:

- Reactor based operations for accepting connections.  Thus, it is not possible to detect when a connection is ready to be accepted (i.e. a connection is queued and waiting to be accepted).
- An higher-level way to detect if the `acceptor` is in a listening state.  Nevertheless, this may be accomplished by querying the acceptor's [`native_handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/native_handle.html).  For example, using [`getsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the value of `SOL_SOCKET/SO_ACCEPTCONN`.