# boost::asio::acceptor - accept new incoming connections while old ones still open

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing proxy server based on boost asio. In the part of my code responsible for accepting incoming connections from browser to proxy server, I'm facing the behaviour i'm not fully understand.

So - I'm creating acceptor object with next constructor:

```
_acceptor(_io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port ), true)
```

start listening here (start_accept):

```
_new_connection.reset(new connection(*_io_services.front(), _connection_id));
_acceptor.async_accept(_new_connection->get_socket(),
                            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

and handle_accept

```
if (!error) {
    _new_connection->start();
}

// continue waiting for incoming connections
start_accept();
```

In general my code for accepting incoming connections is the same as in the [HTTP Server 2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) example

The problem appears only when first incoming connection was not closed, then second incoming will be queued and pending, till first one will be closed.

According to this two answers: 
[boost::asio acceptor reopen and async read after EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926077/boostasio-acceptor-reopen-and-async-read-after-eof)

[How to launch an "event" when my Boost::asio tcp server just start running ( AKA io_service.run() )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829165/how-to-launch-an-event-when-my-boostasio-tcp-server-just-start-running-aka/15883510#15883510)

The acceptor object will add all incoming connections into the queue and will not accept them till pending connection will not be closed.

I want to achieve immediate processing for all incoming connections - so they are not pending in the acceptor's queue, and I did not find any solution so far.

Could you please help me, what is right way to implement this?

connection->start() function

```
void
connection::start() {
    _bsocket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_bbuffer),
            boost::bind(&connection::handle_browser_read_headers,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        ));
}
```

[Graphical representation](http://s15.postimg.org/o7eawdaob/out.png)
UPDATE: boost asio logs

```
@asio|1368460995.389629|0*1|socket@00CCFBE4.async_accept
@asio|1368461003.855113|>1|ec=system:0
@asio|1368461003.855113|1*2|socket@00E26850.async_receive
@asio|1368461003.855113|>2|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=318
@asio|1368461003.856113|1*3|socket@00CCFBE4.async_accept
@asio|1368461003.856113|<1|
@asio|1368461003.856113|2*4|resolver@00E268D8.async_resolve
@asio|1368461003.856113|<2|
@asio|1368461003.866114|>4|ec=system:0,...
@asio|1368461003.866114|4*5|socket@00E26894.async_connect
@asio|1368461003.868114|<4|
@asio|1368461004.204133|>5|ec=system:0
@asio|1368461004.204133|5*6|socket@00E26894.async_send
@asio|1368461004.204133|<5|
@asio|1368461004.204133|>6|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=302
@asio|1368461004.204133|6*7|socket@00E26894.async_receive
@asio|1368461004.204133|<6|
@asio|1368461004.613156|>7|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=16384
@asio|1368461004.613156|7*8|socket@00E26850.async_send
@asio|1368461004.614157|<7|
@asio|1368461004.614157|>8|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=16384
@asio|1368461004.614157|8*9|socket@00E26894.async_receive
@asio|1368461004.614157|<8|
@asio|1368461004.614157|>9|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=1946
@asio|1368461004.614157|9*10|socket@00E26850.async_send
@asio|1368461004.614157|<9|
@asio|1368461004.614157|>10|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=1946
@asio|1368461004.614157|10*11|socket@00E26894.async_receive
@asio|1368461004.614157|<10|
@asio|1368461004.618157|>11|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=14080
@asio|1368461004.618157|11*12|socket@00E26850.async_send
@asio|1368461004.619157|<11|
@asio|1368461004.619157|>12|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=14080
@asio|1368461004.619157|12*13|socket@00E26894.async_receive
@asio|1368461004.619157|<12|
@asio|1368461019.248994|>13|ec=asio.misc:2,bytes_transferred=0
@asio|1368461019.248994|13|socket@00E26894.close
@asio|1368461019.248994|13|socket@00E26850.close
@asio|1368461019.248994|<13|
@asio|1368461019.253994|0|resolver@00E268D8.cancel
@asio|1368461019.253994|>3|ec=system:0
@asio|1368461019.253994|3*14|socket@00E32688.async_receive
@asio|1368461019.254994|3*15|socket@00CCFBE4.async_accept
@asio|1368461019.254994|<3|
@asio|1368461019.254994|>14|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=489
@asio|1368461019.254994|14*16|resolver@00E32710.async_resolve
@asio|1368461019.254994|<14|
@asio|1368461019.281995|>16|ec=system:0,...
@asio|1368461019.281995|16*17|socket@00E326CC.async_connect
@asio|1368461019.282996|<16|
@asio|1368461019.293996|>17|ec=system:0
@asio|1368461019.293996|17*18|socket@00E326CC.async_send
@asio|1368461019.293996|<17|
@asio|1368461019.293996|>18|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=470
@asio|1368461019.293996|18*19|socket@00E326CC.async_receive
@asio|1368461019.293996|<18|
@asio|1368461019.315997|>19|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=11001
@asio|1368461019.315997|19*20|socket@00E32688.async_send
@asio|1368461019.349999|<19|
@asio|1368461019.349999|>20|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=11001
@asio|1368461019.349999|20|socket@00E326CC.close
@asio|1368461019.349999|20|socket@00E32688.close
@asio|1368461019.349999|<20|
@asio|1368461019.349999|0|resolver@00E32710.cancel
```

I found that acceptor's behaviour depends on functions I'm using for read data from server socket. connection class reads data from browser, modifies request url, connects to host and sends request, then reading response from server and writing it back to browser. So at the moment when I need to read server body - I use this function

```
    _ssocket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_sbuffer),
            boost::bind(&connection::handle_server_read_body,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        ));
```

If content-length was not specified in service response headers, I'm reading till EOF. If async_read_some function was called and there is no more data to read on socket it's waiting ~15 sec before EOF will be raised. All new incoming connections during this 15 sec will not be accepted by acceptor.

But if I'm using another variant of async_read -

```
        boost::asio::async_read(_ssocket, boost::asio::buffer(_sbuffer),
            boost::bind(&connection::handle_server_read_body,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        ));
```

Incoming connections are accepted just fine. But it boost::asio::async_read works a bit slow, it is waiting for bunch of data to be read from socket and does not call handler till that data will be read, so - I thought I will specify transfer_at_least

```
        boost::asio::async_read(_ssocket, boost::asio::buffer(_sbuffer), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
            boost::bind(&connection::handle_server_read_body,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        ));
```

Yep, it became better - but problem with accepting new connections returns :/

What is real differences between - async_read_some and boost::asio::async_read - it feels like something is blocked.

Comment: Can you show code inside your start() function? Maybe it is blocking your code, so it does not keep accept()ing.

Comment: I updated question. In general I checked this, I don't use any blocking operations in the connection class. And from the debug logs I see that server::start_accept function was called immediately after handle_accept. But new connection somehow is not accepted by acceptor. It will be accepted only when first one get closed.

Comment: Maybe it is connected to proxy behaviour somehow. I'm using this scenario to reproduce the problem. I'm reading response from server which is missing Content-Lenght header. so I'm using async_read_some function on a server socket. If content length is not specified I'm reading till EOF will be returned. The last call of async_read_some function on server socket, when there is no more data to read takes long amount of time ~10 sec, if new incoming connection appears from browser to proxy during that time - it will not be accepted by acceptor.

Comment: A brief look at the code looks fine.  As long as a thread running the `io_service` is available, then a connection should be accepted if there is an outstanding `async_accept` operation; otherwise the connection is queued within the acceptor until an `accept` operation is initiated.  If you are using Boost.Asio 1.47+, then enabling [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) may provide much better insight into what is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. I Updated question. Well what I can see that async accept was called after first incoming connection was setted up, but async_receive for second incoming connection was called only when first one was closed.

Comment: Have added graphical representation of boost::asio logs. As you can see there, async_accept called immidiately after first connection was seted up, but processing of seconds starts only when first one got finished :/

Comment: The asynchronous chains look correct.  With the code also looking fine, I am inclined to think the problem resides outside of the server code.  Consider using lower-level tools, such as [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to get connection information, and [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to make the connections.  I would start with using netcat on the same host as the server code, then using it from the machines on which the browser(s) are running.

Comment: @TannerSansbury thanks for a tip. I updated my question with latest info I found out. I don't know why yet, but if I'm using boost::asio::async_read instead of socket.async_read_some - new connections accepted immidiately :/

Comment: Interesting.  `boost::async_read` is implemented in terms of `stream.async_read_some`, and the CompletionCondition defaults to [`boost::asio::transfer_all()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_all.html).

Comment: @TannerSansbury thanks, just found that out too. I'm testing on 32k JS file which is downloaded from server. The thing is that async_read_some will always call handler with all data - so I can write that to browser socket. And then - since I don't know the body length and can't figure out do we need to read more or not, I'm calling it again. And here is the problem - because it looks like there is no data to be read from socket - and handler will not be called till EOF will be raised. All incoming connection which appears during that hang - will not be proceeded.

Comment: Rewrite everything to sync functions - found that blocking call on browser socket read_some does not block incoming connections - but the same read_some call on socket to server - blocks all incoming connections to be accepted by accceptor. Asked a different question with code examples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633846/boostasio-read-on-socket-to-server-blocks-all-incoming-connection-on-client-so

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help, but in my server, I'm using the following for my session's read request:

```
boost::asio::async_read( socket(), boost::asio::buffer( _incoming ),
    boost::asio::transfer_at_least( 1 ),
    boost::bind( &server_class::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred ) );
```

I then dump anything I receive into a parser to ensure that it's sane (handling state, etc).

Otherwise, I believe I am doing everything you're doing, based on what I see here.

If this works, then it would seem asio has behavior that isn't intuitive.