# Boost ASIO async_connect succeeds when it should fail, why?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I have a server application in which I accept only one client with `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` and `async_accept`.

I run the client application and successfully connect using a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` and the `async_connect` member function.

Then I make the client crash (CTRL-ALT-DEL).

If I restart the client application, and try to reconnect, it succeeds...

Even though I do not redo an `async_accept` on the server side.

How is this possible?

EDIT:

If the server application is not running, the `async_connect` fails as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible because the acceptor is still in a listening state.  While in a listening state, incoming connections will be queued until they are accepted by an `accept()` operation.  More details on an acceptor's states and operations can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15883510/1053968) answer.

To get the desired behavior, simply `close()` the acceptor after a connection has been accepted.  After the connection closes, transition the acceptor back into a listening state, by performing `open() -> bind() -> listen()`.