# Not accepting when handling async_accept?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to learn ASIO boost but I am having a hard time understanding it. I'd like to make a base layout for a server that should be scalable and performant.

In the following URL there is an example where a small TCP server is setup:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html

What I don't understand is the following part:

```
void start_accept()
{
tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
  tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.io_service());

acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
    boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
  const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
   if (!error)
   {
     new_connection->start();
     start_accept();
   }
}
```

start_accept() eventually calls async_accept() which calls it's handler when it receives data.
And the handler calls start_accept() when being done.

But what would happen if a client would try to connect when the handler would still be running? Isn't it true that the request couldn't be handled because async_accept() wasn't listening anymore?

I hope you can point me in a right direction if I am seeing things in a wrong perspective.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15883510/1053968) answer tries to stress the distinction between state and operations, which may be helpful when learning Boost.Asio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you noticed that the handler posts a new `async_accept` operation immediately after handling the accept (`new_connection->start()`):

```
void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
  const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
   if (!error)
   {
     new_connection->start();   // this posts connection specific asynch operations
     start_accept();            // THIS POSTS THE ASYNC OPERATION AGAIN
   }
}
```

You ask whether there is a race condition there (where the new async accept is not pending at the exact moment a connection is received by the kernel).

There is no such race, since the kernel queues the events in the TCP/IP stack implementation.

---

As a matter of fact, look at the traditional `select`/`poll`/`epoll` approaches, similarly, you don't get an asynchronous signal when a socket changes state. Instead you can poll for it at your own leisure.

The kernel *will* have some limits on time, buffer size and number on the pending events, so if you fail to handle the events for a certain time, they might be gone.

As long as userland code doesn't have direct control over raw hardware, there will never be a race condition there, since the OS stack will have to abstract the lowlevel 
interrupt requests away (otherwise you'd call that OS an [ExoKernel](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExoKernel)).

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean! But I think you mayby misunderstood my question(mayby that's my bad). It's not really when new_connection->start() executes before start_accept() but it's more like: A connection can only be accepted when async_accept is called. But async_accept only accept 1 connection right? Thus when the handler is ran (even if new_connection->start() is async, there's still a little delay right?), no connection can be accepted till it finished and start_accept() is called again and reaches async_accept() again.

Comment: WAIT! I read your answer again and I totally understand what you mean now. So the Operating System keeps the network messages for a while, and eventually when they aren't taken from the queue they will be removed. Is this right? So the small delay doesn't really matter as long as the handler won't take to long. (And therefore we probably need to handle big responses with threads right?) As a last question!: Do you have any idea how long on average for example Windows and Linux might cache those? Is it a question of seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @ChristianVeenman And yes, all code ultimately runs "sequentially" on any CPU. No two events happen at exactly the same time anyways.But that's okay. No two packets can arrive at the same time in hardware anyways. There's many layers of buffering to make it work.  What you want is minimum latency. Which is what you get.